# Create an overall header(how to)

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I know this question won't be well received but I searched far and long and can't find anything, probably not using the right keywords.

I own an online radio station and I want to create a js player that once added to a website will stay in the header on all the domains of the site. I first saw this thing on a tumblr music player(http://scmplayer.net/) , you would add their code to your page and once opened the player will stay as a header even if you browse to other sub-pages of your blog.
I'm searching for this to use in forums, where you change your page so often you can't listen to anything using a built-in radio player.

I found a similar solution by using a button that opens a really small pop-up with the player, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do what I want, and how.

Even a right link, query or term to search for would help me greatly, I don't want someone to do this for me, just point me in the right way.

Edit::
Here's some stuff I forgot to mention. I'm trying to build a code users can just copy paste into their website and have it work.
If it was only for me, I wouldn't be here, since I went trough iframes and jquery to load content too(see www.r4ge.ro).
I can't expect other people to tamper with their website only to embed my radio there, and I can't iframe their site content and add my radio as an index because that would ruin google ranking and indexing.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this, here goes one!

First thing, I'd personally use backbone.js - backbone.js allows you to create 'partial' views that can be updated independently of another.  For your scenario, it seems ideal to create a `header` view and then a `content` view.

Both the header and the content could have their own logic, and update at separate times that you specify and under your control.

Take a look at http://backbonetutorials.com/why-would-you-use-backbone/ to get started. prepare yourself ample time to do a lot of reading and following tutorials.  Backbone takes time to ramp up on, but once you get it, you'll be making some awesome apps!

Comment: I'm taking a look into this, it looks very interesting especialyl since I am using tons of jquery and divs for my current project.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have three options:

1. The one you found, opening a really small pop-up (perhaps with just the media controls visible), so that when the user navigates, it isn't affected by the page being torn down.
2. The same thing using frames.
3. The same thing using ajax to load content when navigating instead of actually navigating.

As you didn't like #1 much, let's look at #2, then come back to #3.

When the use opens the player, you'd really be going to a page with the player and a very large `iframe` with the rest of the content:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- ... -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- player here -->
<iframe class="main" src="main.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

You'd use CSS to make that as seamless as you could. To make it linkable, you could use a large fragment in the URL which is the URL of the page that should go in the frame, e.g.:

`http://example.com/#forum.html&section=23`

When your main page loads, you grab the fragment, and use it as the `src` on the `iframe`.

You can listen for navigation events on the iframe and update the hash fragment on the main window, so that bookmarks work, and/or have JavaScript on each page of your site that might be navigated to that tells the container page (`parent`) what its URL is.

#3 is similar to #2 except that rather than letting navigation happen the normal way, you load everything via ajax as the user clicks around, loading it into (say) a main content `div` rather than an `iframe`. This can also use hash fragments to ensure that it's fully linkable/bookmarkable, etc., but requires that all links in the pages loaded get rewritten so they update the hash fragment rather than the main URL instead.

#2 and #3 (and #1) all have their advantages and disadvantages. #1 is probably the least work. #2 probably comes in second, then #3, but I could have those backward.

Here's a quick and dirty version of #2 that polls for hash updates so that the pages loaded in the frame don't have to know anything about this at all. Note that all you'd have to give to the other people is the page; their pages remain the same. If they're concerned about page rank, they'll want to include the canonical URL of their pages in the markup.

`withplayer.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example</title>
<style>
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
div.player {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 2px;
}
iframe.content {
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:30px;
    width: 100%;
    /*bottom: 0px; Sigh, this works on elements other than iframe, see 'resize' JavaScript below */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="player"></div>
<iframe class="content"></iframe>
<script>
(function() {
    // Fill in our "player"
    var dt = new Date().toISOString();
    document.querySelector(".player").innerHTML =
        "This div is our pretend player: The div was loaded on " +
        dt.substring(0, 10) + " at " + dt.substring(11, 19) + ".";

    // Get the iframe
    var content = document.querySelector(".content");

    // Listen for hash changes
    window.onhashchange = loadContent;

    // Load any initial hash we have
    loadContent();

    // Get our current hash, without the leading #
    function getHash() {
        return location.hash.replace(/^#/, '');
    }

    // Get the hash equivalent of the current content in the content iframe
    function getContentHash() {
        var loc, hash;

        loc = content && content.contentWindow && content.contentWindow.location;
        hash = loc && loc != "about:blank" ? loc.pathname + loc.search + loc.hash : undefined;
        return hash;
    }

    // Load the content for the current hash
    function loadContent() {
        // If we have an initial hash, apply to the iframe
        var hash = getHash();
        if (hash) {
            content.src = hash;
        }
    }

    // Poll for changes to the frame's location, update our hash if
    // it doesn't match
    setInterval(pollContent, 100);

    function pollContent() {
        var newHash;

        newHash = getContentHash();
        if (newHash !== undefined && newHash !== getHash()) {
            location.hash = "#" + newHash;
        }
    }

    // Stoopid iframes won't stick to the bottom, have to resize their height
    resize();
    window.onresize = resize;
    function resize() {
        content.style.height = (window.innerHeight - 30) + "px";
    }
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AronH.: Option #2 is still feasible, you just have to give them the page and tell them to ensure they provide the canonical URL of their content in a meta tag; no changes to their pages (other than adding a button to open the player). I've posted an example.

Comment: I can't do that, I can't modify their page. I guess I'll stick to the pop-up and some javascript tricks, I have a chrome extension set after all, maybe people will start installing it

Comment: @AronH.: Again: No modifications to *their* pages required. You send them (a much more debugged and complete version of) this page, and they use it with their **existing** pages, unchanged (other than the recommendation that they use canonical meta tags).

Comment: well yeah but they need to change their index to this page, don't they?

Comment: @AronH.: Only if they want the player opened automatically. (Er, in the above, I should have said that they need to change their pages to add the canonical URL **and** to add a means of opening the player.)